# Как поставить поток на паузу и возобновить в нужный момент

Tags: linux, c

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>



void *threadfunc(){
        while(1){
                printf("i am thread \n");
                sleep(1);
                }
}

void main(){
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadfunc, NULL);
        sleep(2);
        pthread_kill(thread, SIGSTOP);
        printf("signal sent \n");
        sleep(2);
        printf("i am main thread \n");
}
```

Я ожидаю от этой программы следующей работы: стартует функция `main()`, создается поток `thread`, 2 раза выводится надпись  `i am thread`, останавливается вывод информации с потока, пользователь видит надпись, что сигнал отправлен и через 2 секунды надпись что это главный поток.

Однако, команда `pthread_kill(thread, SIGSTOP);` останавливает основной поток тоже, хотя, как я понял, она посылает сигнал только указанному потоку( в моем случае, `thread`-у).

В будущем, программа должна остонавливать и возобновлять поток (путем сигнала `SIGСONT`), поэтому вариант с`pthread_cancel()` и снова `pthread_create()` не рассматриваются. В связи с чем, возник вопрос - как поставить на паузу поток?

Comment: В Unix сигналы посылаются процессу, а не потоку, почитайте notes у ``man pthread_kill``. На каком потоке оно обработается не известно (тут еще написано https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005719/which-thread-handles-the-signal). Кроме того ожидать что что-то выполнятся 2 раза тут нельзя: потоки не синхронизированы, и не известно сколько раз выполнится второй поток прежде, чем первый пошлет kill.

Comment: Напихай локов по коду и при сигконт выставляй этот лок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть куча вариантов общения потоков. `pthread_mutex` - для блокировки чего-нибудь. `pthread_cond_signal` , `pthread_cond_wait` - посылать сигнал, ждать его (блокировка с помощью `mutex` - обязательна). И ещё универсальный вариант `sem_t` : `sem_wait` - ждать момента когда что-то можно, `sem_post` - дать разрешение любому потоку. Попробуйте все и выберете.